# Picker views are synchronizing all text boxes

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, pickerview

I have an issue involving picker views in XCode. When I run the simulation and choose an option in the picker view, the text pops up in both text boxes (classOne and classThree in my code) controlling all (2 currently, will add more later) which have  a picker view.

I have been trying to solve this (having individual picker views that are not synchronized and can put different choices in different text boxes) but nothing is working even though I have made two separate picker views and two separate cases in the functions. Here is my code for the class.

```
import UIKit

 
 class UnweightedGPACalculator: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var classOne: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var classTwo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var classThree: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var classFour: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var classFive: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var classSix: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var classSeven: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var classEight: UITextField!

let vars = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"]
let vars2 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"]
@IBOutlet weak var mainScreen: UITextView!
let currentText = UITextField()

var pickerView1 = UIPickerView()

var pickerView2 = UIPickerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    pickerView1.dataSource = self
    pickerView1.dataSource = self
    
    pickerView2.delegate = self
    
    pickerView2.dataSource = self
    
    classOne.tag = 1
    classThree.tag = 2
    
    classOne.inputView = pickerView1
    classThree.inputView = pickerView2
    classOne.textAlignment = .center
    classThree.textAlignment = .center
    
    classOne.placeholder = "Class 1"
    classThree.placeholder = "Class 2"
    
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1
}
   
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    if pickerView.tag == classOne.tag{
    return 5
    }
    else{
    return 5
    }

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?{

    if pickerView.tag == classOne.tag{
        return vars[row]
    }
    else{
        return vars2[row]
    }

}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    classOne.text = vars[row]
    classOne.resignFirstResponder()
    
    classThree.text = vars2[row]
    classThree.resignFirstResponder()
}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Code Below is for a button unrelated to the pickerViews as far as I know. You may see extra long/unnecessary code there but works fine and am not interested in simplifying as it does not change the function of the button.

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
@IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let c1 = classOne.text
    let c2 = classTwo.text
    let c3 = classThree.text
    let c4 = classFour.text
    let c5 = classFive.text
    let c6 = classSix.text
    let c7 = classSeven.text
    let c8 = classEight.text
    let group = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8]
    var t2 : Double
    var temp : Int = -1
    var total = 0
    var num = 0
    for item in group {
        if item == "A" || item == "A+" || item == "A-" || item == "A*"{
            temp = 4
        }
        else if  item == "B" || item == "B+" || item == "B-" || item == "B*"{
            temp = 3
        }
        else if  item == "C" || item == "C+" || item == "C-" || item == "C*"{
            temp = 2
        }
        else if  item == "D" || item == "D+" || item == "D-" || item == "D*"{
            temp = 1
        }
        else if  item == "F" || item == "F+" || item == "F-" || item == "F*" {
            temp = 0
            
        }
        else if item == "" {
            temp = -3
        }
        else {
            temp = -2
            
        }
        if  temp >= 0 {
            total+=temp
            num+=1
        }
        
    }
    if temp >= 0 || temp == -3{
        t2 = Double(total)/Double(num)
        var doubleStr = String(format: "%.2f", ceil(t2*100)/100)
        if (t2*100).remainder(dividingBy: 10) == 0{
            doubleStr = String(format: "%.1f", ceil(t2*100)/100)
        }
        mainScreen.text = doubleStr
        
    }
    else{
        mainScreen.text = "Error"
    }
}

}
```

Comment: "trying to solve this"  What is 'this'?

Comment: @ElTomato I mean  having the picker views not synchronized so that one cannot affect another text box. I have clarified it just now.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.